# How can I write a test to wait for close app using Flutter Driver

Tags: android, flutter, integration-testing, ui-testing, flutterdriver

I have to test my agreement when the app is first launched: if the user do not agree, than the app must close.

Most of the test are already working but I couldn't figure out how to test if the app has closed.

Is there any way to test this behavior and "expect for close app"?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the app
2. Initialise flutter driver.
3. Check that flutter driver is not null
4. Close the app (the app should be closed and not backgrounded)
5. driver.[checkHealth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver/checkHealth.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger app exit you may verify if the app was exited by its exit code

```
expect(exitCode, 0);
```

I am using this approach in my tests and it works great.

usage in a sample test:
https://github.com/maheshmnj/navbar_router/blob/885c68ae974250167df3c1dccee3e6474f5ddd39/test/navbar_router_test.dart#L210